# SimpleDateFormatter throws ParseException

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I have these two methods that are written right now.  As the scenario goes, when I grab a data field from the database, it is in BigDecimal format.  So I decided to write a test for it (the formatDate() method).  I pass in the BigDecimal to the method, but it appears I have written some peice of this code wrong.  From what I have seen in examples and the SimpleDateFormat API, I think I have written the code correctly, but I cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong to have it throw a parseEx.  Can someone give me a hint at what is going on?

```
private void loadMap() {
    //TODO:  Uncomment when finished testing.
    //DO OTHER STUFF
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(12051998);
    System.out.println(formatDate(bd));
}

private String formatDate(BigDecimal bd) {
    String value = bd.toString();   
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");   
    try {
        return format.parse(value);
    } catch (ParseException pEx) {
        logger.error(pEx);
        return "Bad Date Format";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,  Warmest Regards,

- Josh

Comment: `BigDecimal` is an odd choice for holding date values.

Comment: @GriffeyDog It's IBM / Genelco software for DB2 on an AS/400.  Everything is odd.

Comment: The answer is good, but you may want to also consider using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
```

`return format.parse(value);`// **value should be of Date type not String** .

Try this  to change format of the date from MMddyyyy to MM/dd/yyyy: It works fine for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(12051998);
    String s = bd.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse(s);
    String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
}
```

Output:

```
12051998
12/05/1998
```

Comment: I have updated the method to MMddyyyy The message I am getting is:  Unparseable date: "12051998"

Comment: @JoshGooding you want to change format of the date from MMddyyyy to MM/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: yes I want to convert 12051998 to 12/05/1998.  It worked.  I was unaware that I had to basically do a double conversion on the date.  I tried doing it in one step, and didn't realize.  Seems like you cannot do everything in one step.  Thank you!